# Change network cards names in Network Manager applet

Tags: 14.04, network-manager

I have four network cards of the same type in my PC, and all of them look the same in network manager applet:

```
EthernetNetwork (Broadcom NetXtreme BCM5704 Gigabit Ethernet)
disconnected
EthernetNetwork (Broadcom NetXtreme BCM5704 Gigabit Ethernet)
disconnected
EthernetNetwork (Broadcom NetXtreme BCM5704 Gigabit Ethernet)
disconnected
EthernetNetwork (Broadcom NetXtreme BCM5704 Gigabit Ethernet)
disconnected
```

Is there a way to change name for each card in network manager applet to distinguish interfaces?

System is Ubuntu 14.04.